# Does brain activity generate anything outside our bodies?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, biophysics, biology, perception

I have been reading recently about the Law of Attraction and while I don't believe in its 'scientifical' basis it did make me think about whether our brain produces any kind of activity strictly outside our bodies on a quantum level. Has any scientist ever attempted to observe that?

Comment: seems to be a research project https://engineering.mit.edu/engage/ask-an-engineer/can-brain-waves-interfere-with-radio-waves/

Comment: well an fMRI is a form of remote sensing....but it could consider active, not passive.

Comment: As I am typing this message, my brain is initiating a long chain of quantum mechanical events - nerve impulses, muscle movements, electromagnetic contact forces and a whole slew of activity within my iPad, my WiFi router and many internet servers. The end result is that these letters are appearing on my screen and on yours. Does that count ?

Comment: @gandalf61 I didn't mean in such an indirect sense. I meant if we put some sort of measuring device into the area around and outside the human head would we witness something that we would be able to prove it's coming from our brain?

Comment: @MichaelMunta Like electroencephalography https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroencephalography ?

Comment: @gandalf61 anything of that sort that is not in direct contact with the head? And what are the types of information we can get out of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several non-invasive medical imaging techniques that can detect activity in the brain at different levels of temporal and spatial resolution. These include [magnetic resonance imaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_resonance_imaging), [positron emission tomography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron_emission_tomography), [electroencephalography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroencephalography) and [magnetoencephalography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetoencephalography). However, the electrical and magnetic fields produced by brain activity are very weak, and all of these techniques require highly sensitive and complex equipment with sensors in close proximity to the head.

As far as we know, the only other way in which human brain activity can affect objects outside of the body (apart from these very specialised imaging techniques) is by firing neurons which contract muscles.

Comment: And now a very dumb question perhaps, but is it at all possible that we would ever be able to manipulate physical matter using our minds alone or is that forever forbidden by the already known physical laws?

Comment: @MichaelMunta Using our brains alone ? No. The energy involved in brain activity is very small, and must be amplified to have measurable effects on external objects. This amplification requires either biological infrastructure (neurons, muscles) or some very complex technology.

Comment: How about evolution? Can it make a change in the power of our brain in a very long time?

Comment: @MichaelMunta If you have a question about evolution you should post it on the Biology Stack Exchange.